# Why is this ESLint override file in a create-react-app not finding errors?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, create-react-app, eslint

I set up a React site with `create-react-app` and am using VSCode to edit it.

I want to override some of the ESLint rules that it has.

Therefore I installed these packages:

`npm i -D eslint-config-airbnb eslint-config-prettier eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y eslint-plugin-prettier prettier`

and then created the following `.eslintrc` file:

[image]

However, the rules that I'm adding don't take any effect, e.g. even though I specify that I want to force single quotes and force semi-colons, I have both JavaScript and TypeScript files throughout my application which have single and double quotes, and some lines have semi-colons and some don't, but ESLint in VSCode shows no errors, and I am able to build successfully, and the site builds and publishes without errors at Netlify.

To add to the confusion, only in the .eslintrc file itself does ESLint seem to find errors, yet as you can see above, it finds an error that it shouldn't find: on the rule that states it should only allow single quotes, it says that using single quotes is an error. (!)

What's going on here?

**ADDENDUM**

I added an `.env` file with the line `EXTEND_ESLINT = "true"` and now even though VSCode doesn't find any errors, when I `npm start` it finds errors in the `ServiceWorker.js` file in `src`, although my rule is set to force single quotes (`"quotes": ["error", "single"],`) and it is saying that the file needs double quotes:

[image]

In fact, I see I can remove the `quotes` rule altogether and having the `.env` file in my root directory with the line `EXTEND_ESLINT = "true"` will cause these double quote errors to be generated on a development build.

Comment: Your quote style rule doesn't apply to your `.eslintrc` file because it does not apply to the language that file is written in (JSON). Note that this is not a question of style, JSON does not support single quoted keys or values.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes, of course, I overlooked that. But you can see in the screenshot that it is finding an error with the trailing comma. Yet in my other files (JavaScript and TypeScript), I have trailing commas, e.g. on JavaScript objects, and it doesn't find an error. How do I get ESLint to check other files besides its own `.eslintrc` file?

Comment: In fact, I realize now that if I remove the three `import` rules, it does find these errors in other files, but why would it ignore the `quotes` and `semi` rules?

Comment: For instance, I can change `"quotes": ["error", "single"],` to `"quotes": ["error", "double"],`, and it still finds nothing. It seems to be completely ignoring this rule. Do I need to specify somehow that it should explicitly override these rules, e.g. as with a CSS `!important` statement?

Comment: The VS Code eslint plug-in does not look at .env files AFAIK. Also Are you still using trailing commas in your config file? Don't do that. Also, see if eslint works from the command line